# How to get zend to initialize? I'm having difficulty

Tags: php, html, wamp, zune

Before you thumb me down for being idiot help me understand why it's spitting errors. I am new to Zune and it does not seem to be intuitive.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run php composer.phar install or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in C:\wamp\www\ZendSkeletonApplication-master\init_autoloader.php on line 51`

`RuntimeException: Unable to load ZF2. Run php composer.phar install or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable. in C:\wamp\www\ZendSkeletonApplication-master\init_autoloader.php on line 51`

I don't get why I need to be a level 10 magical elf to be able to upload an image to illustrate my issue.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I left a comment that was appropriate at the time of reviewing the post. You did really good when you realize that the post need editing. That's what community does — and you should be ok with it. And btw, I didn't downvote your post.

Comment: @Stankyass - you can edit your question to include links to your images, and someone will edit them in properly for you. As to why - if there's no limit to who can edit images into questions, I'm sure it'll be no time at all before spammers are adding all sorts of exciting things in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open a cmd window and change directory to your project. You then need to type the following:

```
php composer.phar install
```

This should handle dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your response. Goodness this site is restrictive I can't even write thanks without it having the correct amount of characters.